# How can I simplify my code in R?

Tags: r

I have the following ugly code from R, and I would just like to simplify, so that the code is more practical and takes up less lines. It's just the same command being run over and over again.

```
x$Avg..session.duration..seconds.<- 
as.numeric(x$Avg..session.duration..seconds.)
x$All.conv..value...cost<- as.numeric(x$All.conv..value...cost)
x$All.conv..value <- as.numeric(x$All.conv..value)
x$Interactions<- as.numeric(x$Interactions)
x$Views<- as.numeric(x$Views)
x$Total.cost<- as.numeric(x$Total.cost)
x$Avg..CPM<- as.numeric(x$Avg..CPM)
x$Cost<- as.numeric(x$Cost)
x$Impressions <- as.numeric(x$Impressions)
x$Clicks<- as.numeric(x$Clicks)
x$Bounce.rate <- as.numeric(x$Clicks)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

If nothing within is a factor:

```
x[] <- lapply(x, as.numeric))
```

If you do have factors, you need to convert with as.character first:

```
x[] <- lapply(x, function(y) as.numeric(as.character(y)))
```

If you don't want to convert in-place, you wrap the `lapply` expression with `as.data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern you will want to follow is

1. Identify the columns that need to be changed.
2. Use `lapply`

If you only want to convert character values, you may use

```
# Identify character values (all character values)
to_num <- vapply(X, is.character, logical(1))

X[to_num] <- lapply(X[to_num], as.numeric)
```

If you have only a very specific list of character values to convert, something like this will work.

```
to_num <- c("Avg..session.duration..seconds.",
            "All.conv..value...cost",
            "All.conv..value",
            "Interactions",
            "Views")
X[to_num] <- lapply(X[to_num], as.numeric)
```

If you have a mixture of characters and factors, Matthew's answer works well.